# SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates brokes credentialForTrust

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, pki

I want to connect to HTTPS server which uses certificate signed by custom CA. I would like to have certification's authority CA certificate hardwired in my IOS application. I tried this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    .....
    NSString *rootCertPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"qfixca" 
                          ofType:@"der"];
    self.rootCertData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:rootCertPath];
    .....
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
           [NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:
            NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];

    [theRequest setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                                    initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        NSLog(@"Connection establisted successfully");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed.");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;

    CFDataRef certDataRef = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)self.rootCertData;
    SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certDataRef);

    // Establish a chain of trust anchored on our bundled certificate.
    CFArrayRef certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)&cert, 1, NULL);

    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, certArrayRef);
    SecTrustResultType result;
    OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &result);
    if (status == errSecSuccess &&
       (result == kSecTrustResultProceed ||
       result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified))
    {
        NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"sending response");
    }
    else {
        [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Problem is that after I added my root CA certificate as an anchor with

```
SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates
```

call

```
[challenge.sender useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

does not work as I expected. I got The certificate for this server is invalid error. When I skip adding my CA cert as an anchor and calling directly

```
[challenge.sender useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

it works,but I cannot verify servers certificate. What am I doing wrong? Big thanks!

Adam

Comment: My first suggestion would be to verify the .der format file.   In particular, make sure that it's binary and not text encoded, as `SecCertificateCreateWithData` requires the binary version.  What is the result of your `SecTrustEvaluate`?  And, you should verify the `[protectionSpace authenticationMethod]` before performing the CA check.

Comment: .der file should be OK,I double checked it. Also added check for `[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust`

Comment: `SecTrustEvaluate` returns `errSecSuccess`. SItuation is still the same

Comment: I discovered that this happens only when server requires client certificate!

Comment: You sure you are getting ONLY a isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust ? And not something else (e.g. auth or hostname) earlier ??  When there is not yet a chain to respond to.

Have a look at https://github.com/dirkx/Security-Pinning-by-CA/tree/master/Security%20Pinning%20by%20CA and specifically https://github.com/dirkx/Security-Pinning-by-CA/blob/master/Security%20Pinning%20by%20CA/PinnedHTTPSConnection.m which deals with all 5 possible permutations.

Comment: @user2153861 - `errSecSuccess` means the call to `SecTrustEvaluate` succeeded. You still need to check `result` to ensure its either `kSecTrustResultProceed` or `kSecTrustResultUnspecified`. See Apple TN2232 [HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) and QA1360 [Describing the kSecTrustResultUnspecified error](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1360/_index.html).